# ERROR with deepface install: Could not build wheels for opencv-python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, anaconda, deepface

I try to install deepface and got a lot of red messages. the error msg in the end:
ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-contrib-python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects.

I'm on windows from anaconda prompt
update opencv (4.5.5.64 and then tried 4.8.0.74)
update pip (21.3.1)
numpy as well (1.13.3)
python version - 3.6.5

Comment: if you're on windows, it shouldn't even try to build any wheel for opencv. opencv has binary packages for python. -- do you think the information in your question is sufficient to answer it? please review [ask] and [mre]. present the fruits of your research too.

Comment: on my PC (windows) i'm using simple Jupyter notebook. I have anaconda. and my installations is made from this prompt (cmd). i don't know what it should or shouldn't, but this is the case.